# Push notification for Voip (type 4) windows phone 8 limit

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, voip, mpns

Is push notification and voip free in Windows Phone 8 as same as other types of push notification? I was trying the ChatterBox example. Will I need to pay for Voip when it will run on production? Please provide any link or source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need pay for `VOIP`. Concerning `Push Notifications`, there is a limit 500 push notifications per subscription, per day. If it is not enough you will need to pay for a certificate. More details http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941099(v=vs.105).aspx